# Only once data.sql file has to be execute

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I Don't want to execute `data.sql` file every time I want `data.sql` file to be execute once and after that when ever I run my application file it has to by pass this file. because when ever I am running the application it executes the `data.sql` file and for that duplicate entries are in the table.

Comment: The answer depends heavily on your application logic. You need do add some logic which detects if data.sql was already run. So just define the "by pass criteria", check for it at first and run data.sql only if needed. Please note that this adds a constant overhead to you app. Might be worth to think of the opposite path. Though an error when the app is started without data.sql has been *EVER* run then run it and start you app.

Comment: can we do something in application.properties file for that it will check the data.sql file

Comment: There no config for disabling this in `application.yml`. What you can do it add proper constraints in DB side and enable this `spring.datasource.continue-on-error`

Comment: thanks, it is working now.

Comment: but it is not a good solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use some database migration tool such as Flyway or Liquidbase, then each time when start the app, it will know if the changes have already been applied.

Eg:
data.sql will be renamed to something like initial_data_V100.

Then this will be stored under a schema table (Generated and used by Flyway/Liquidbase) like:
Id, Schema_version, script_name, checksum
1, V100, initial_data_V100,234234

Each time you start the app, it will see if you have already applied that schema changes.

Next time you want to add more changes, all you have to do is create a new file with and increment the version eg: V101.sql. Flyway or Liquidbase will pick it up and apply the schema changes

Answer (score 0):

Use this parameter in your application.properties file

`spring.datasource.continue-on-error`